# How to Lift and Shift from OpenStack to GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, openstack, disk-image

I have previously had an OpenStack based cloud environmnent in which I had virtual servers. I have migrated to GCP and while I've refactored everything to be cloud native (and especially k8s), I'd like to move the disk images to GCP for archival purposes and so that I can access them by starting an instance in GCE.

I've made a snapshot of a server and downloaded it with glance cli tool, but I have hard time getting it work in GCP (If that's even possible?). I've tried importing it as an image both on GUI and CLI. If I denote the OS (Centos 7), the import process does seem to find it in the raw disk image, but the import process ends with

```
[import-image]: 2020-09-23T08:22:48.732Z step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-image-translate-disk-1zq15": "TranslateFailed: error: Verify that you have specified the correct operating system in the `--os` flag. If you are bringing your own license (BYOL), also verify that your subscription is eligible to be run on GCP."
```

If I don't denote the OS, the import succeeds but the instance is not bootable from the image.

So my questions are: Is what I'm trying to do actually possible and if so, how? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this article [Choosing an import method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import). Which ways have you tried? Please provide more details.

Comment: I have tried [importing virtual disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks) with and without denoting the OS.

Comment: Thank you. Please provide more details about your steps with commands and outputs: **1**. checking [limits](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks); **2**. checking [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#permissions); **3**. checking [compatibility](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#precheck); **4**. [importing a bootable virtual disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#bootable)